# How can I create a manual timer trigger in my http function of Azure Functions

Tags: function, azure, azure-functions

I want to create a manual timer trigger in my http function.
For example,
When my function get a http request, I want to create a timer trigger manually so that trigger another function after 30 minutes.

Does anyone know how can i be done in Azure Functions?

Comment: You do not need to create that timer trigger function, you can try to send a queue message and specify ``initialVisibilityDelay`` with 30 min delay when your http function get the request, and then you can use a queue trigger function to process the queue message.

Comment: Detailed information about [initialVisibilityDelay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.cloudqueue.addmessage?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=azurestorage-8.1.3#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Queue_CloudQueue_AddMessage_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Queue_CloudQueueMessage_System_Nullable_System_TimeSpan__System_Nullable_System_TimeSpan__Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Queue_QueueRequestOptions_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_OperationContext_)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a dup of [Programmatically Schedule one-time execution of Azure function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46395889/programmatically-schedule-one-time-execution-of-azure-function/46415774#46415774)

Have your real work done via a Queue Trigger, and then you can queue a message with deferred visibility:

```
CloudQueue queueOutput; // same queue as trigger listens on 
var strjson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message); // message is your payload
var cloudMsg = new CloudQueueMessage(strjson);

var delay = TimeSpan.FromHours(1); 
queueOutput.AddMessage(cloudMsg, initialVisibilityDelay: delay);
```

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned earlier in my comment, if possible, you can insert a message and specify [initialVisibilityDelay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.cloudqueue.addmessage?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=azurestorage-8.1.3#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Queue_CloudQueue_AddMessage_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Queue_CloudQueueMessage_System_Nullable_System_TimeSpan__System_Nullable_System_TimeSpan__Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Queue_QueueRequestOptions_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_OperationContext_) with 30 min delay when your http function get the request, and then you can use a queue trigger function to process the queue message and do some tasks.

If you create Azure functions on Azure portal, you can [reference `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#referencing-external-assemblies) and use the following code to add message in your http trigger function.

**Reference assemblies and import namespaces**

```
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue;
```

**Add message and specify initialVisibilityDelay**

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("{storage_connection_string}");

CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();

CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("mymes");

queue.CreateIfNotExists();

CloudQueueMessage message = new CloudQueueMessage("{message_body}");
queue.AddMessage(message, initialVisibilityDelay: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
```

Besides, you can [create a function triggered by Azure Queue storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-queue-triggered-function) to process your queue messages.