# Azure functions to run at particular date and time

Tags: azure-functions

Is it possible to configure an azure function to run at a specific date and time? the only option i see is timer based scheduling which looks like a corn job.

Please suggest how I can get azure function to run on specific times.

Comment: Do you want it to run only once?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46395889/programmatically-schedule-one-time-execution-of-azure-function

Answer (score 1):

Per my understanding, you could use the [Scheduled messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sequencing#scheduled-messages) from Service Bus and set the `ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc` property when sending a message. This property is used to submit messages to a queue or topic for delayed processing. The document gives an example: schedule a job to become available for processing by a system at a certain time. I think this is what you want.

Then yo could use a `ServiceBusTrigger` with your Function to triggering the scheduled queue message. Further more about `Azure Service Bus bindings` you could refer to this doc: [Azure Service Bus bindings for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus).