# How can I programmatically create an event scheduler in Azure from C#?

Tags: azure

I am a beginner in azure, previously I had a logic app
That it had a timer that runs an enpoint every day to check which employees have their birthday to send an email.

[image]

I would like not to review employees' birthdays every day, since there will be more types of notifications to send.

**What do you recommend me to do or what service in Azure to use?**

*When I detect that an employee whose birthday is registered on December 26, for example, I can programmatically create a Schedule event in Azure , which can be executed every December 26, so that it calls my enpoit birthday.*

• My endpoints are developed in ASP NET CORE 6

• My DB is in PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what is the total number of user. But for 2 users you will end with 2 schedules. If you have 1000 users... you will have 1000 Schedules? what happen if at least 2 have the same date?
Maybe you need to think in another approach. You can trigger a single schedule, to check birthdays every single day, and then put a message in Service Bus, where your birthday module will take the message and send the notification for the user.
Sorry just an idea. :D

Comment: @Alfreado Fernandez

Thank you,

I have found some similarities with what I would like to do

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46395889/programmatically-schedule-one-time-execution-of-azure-function

I understand the issue that the event service would grow. but I would like to see if there is something in azure to be able to manage it correctly.